# Problem resolution needed for building ROS2 from source

Tags: ros2, raspberry-pi, build-from-source, ogre

I am using Ubuntu 23.10 on a Raspberry Pi 5 to build ROS2 from source, as specified in
"Ros 2 Documentation: Iron" https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html#get-ros-2-code

1. I was unable to install ros-dev-tools with the error "The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu mantic Release' does not have a Release file."
2. To correct generated errors I installed git, python3-rosdep2, colcon, cmake, libacl1-dev, libtinyxml2-dev, libasio-dev, libxranr-dev, libxcursor-dev, python-pyqt5, and lifreetype6-dev
3. colcon build --symlink-install now makes it up to rviz_rendering and fails:

---

```
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.27/Module/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):  
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (PkgConfig)  
  does not match the name of the calling package (libcurl_vendor). This can  
  lead to problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result  
  variables (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.  
Call Stack (most recent call first):  
  /usr/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:99 (find_package_handle_standard_args)    
  /home/hal-cat/ros2_iron/install/libcurl_vendor/share/libcurl_vendor/cmake/libcurl_vendor-  extras.cmake:21 (include)  
  /home/hal-cat/ros2_iron/install/libcurl_vendor/share/libcurl_vendor/cmake  /libcurl_vendorConfig.cmake:41 (include)  
  /home/hal-cat/ros2_iron/install/resource_retriever/share/resource_retriever/cmake   /ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:21 (find_package)  
  /home/hal-cat/ros2_iron/install/resource_retriever/share/resource_retriever/cmake  /resource_retrieverConfig.cmake:41 (include)  
  CMakeLists.txt:40 (find_package)  
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.  

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:100 (target_link_libraries):  
  Target "rviz_rendering" links to:  

    rviz_ogre_vendor::OgreOverlay  

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:  

    * There is a typo in the target name.  
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.  
    * An ALIAS target is missing.  



CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:259 (target_link_libraries):  
  Target "movable_text_test_target" links to:  

    rviz_ogre_vendor::OgreOverlay  

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:  

    * There is a typo in the target name.  
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.  
    * An ALIAS target is missing.
```

Answer (score 2):

On Raspberry Pi 4, you should install Ubuntu 22.04, as that is the current Tier 1 supported OS. Ubuntu 23 is not supported by REP-2000.

You can see a bunch more context on all the challenges on this ticket:

- [[Meta-Ticket] J-turtle changes for Ubuntu 23/24 #1452](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/1452)

Just higher on the tutorial you linked, it lists the [system requirements](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html#system-requirements).

Is there a reason you are doing a different OS version than recommended?

Edit: Ah yes, [PI5 doesn't support Ubuntu 22](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi). I recommend using Docker for now. Once PI5 can support Ubuntu 24, and ROS 2 Jazzy is released, that should when you can run ROS 2 Jazzy on host OS without much difficulty.

Comment: 22.04 does not support the Raspberry Pi 5, which is the platform I am trying to compile for.

Comment: Got it. That's not a supported combination. I recommend docker for the time being until J-Turtle is out.